# Electronic copy of Glivenko, ‘Sur quelque points de la logique de M. Brouwer’

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, intuitionism

Glivenko is cited *i.a.* in the [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/):

> Glivenko, V., 1929, “Sur quelques points de la logique de M. Brouwer,” *Académie Royale de Belgique, Bulletins de la classe des sciences*, 5 (15): 183–188.

I’m having a little trouble finding an electronic copy. A [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=%22Sur+quelque+points+de+la+logique+de+M.+Brouwer) gives lots of citations in other papers. [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22Sur+quelque+points+de+la+logique+de+M.+Brouwer) has no copy.

The *Bulletins* are [partially digitised](https://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/bibliography/163259) up to 1925. It is also not possible to find the paper on the [webpage](https://academieroyale.be/fr/publications-academie-toutes-publications/) of the Académie (I set the year to 1929).

Comment: I have stupidly overlooked that the _Bulletins_ appear to be held in Oxford too, even if their contents haven’t been indexed. Glivenko died in 1940 so the article should be in the public domain in the UK now.

Comment: I now have a copy and will clean up the scan before uploading it. I may as well translate it into English too since it’s fairly short. If anybody wants it urgently do reply here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A copy is available [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sur_quelque_points_de_la_logique_de_M_Brouwer.pdf), as is one of [Glivenko’s preceding note](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sur_la_logique_de_M_Brouwer.pdf).